# Disallow templates that are explicitly specified

Tags: c++

I want to have a wide template that 'does whatever it needs to' except for when I have explicitly specified the case.

Specifically, I am overloading `operator()` to use it for a matrix index of a multidimensional matrix. I also want to allow specifying an arbitrary number of indices using an iterator. Ideally I'd have the following signatures:

```
operator()(size_t);
operator()(size_t,size_t);
operator()(size_t,size_t,size_t);
...

template<class Iterator> operator()(Iterator,Iterator);
```

The problem is that `operator()(size_t,size_t)` is never reached, because the compiler is also able to template `template<class Iterator> operator()(Iterator,Iterator)`. How can I avoid this?

An obvious solution is to use `std::vector<size_t>::iterator` instead of `Iterator`. I've tried this, but this narrows the usage elsewhere.

---

A minimal example:

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
private:
  double data[9];

public:
  Foo(){};

  double& operator()(size_t i, size_t j)
  {
    std::cout << "operator()(size_t i, size_t j)" << std::endl;
    return data[0];
  }

  template<class Iterator>
  double& operator()(Iterator first, Iterator last)
  {
    std::cout << "operator()(Iterator first, Iterator last)" << std::endl;
    return data[0];
  }

};


int main()
{
  Foo bar;

  bar(0,1);
}
```

Outputs:

```
operator()(Iterator first, Iterator last)
```

whereas I want this case to output

```
operator()(size_t i, size_t j)
```

Comment: `0`, `1` are `int`, not `std::size_t`.

Comment: Read [enable_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if). Side note: indexing with `operator()` is counter-intuitive, use `operator[]` instead

Comment: You might use SFINAE for the template version, with `!std::is_integral<T>::value` for example.

Comment: @PasserBy: `operator()` can take several parameter, `operator[]` not.(can still use `std::pair`/`std::tuple` as argument though).

Comment: @Jarod42 True. However, I want to avoid having to type-cast each time that I manually enter the index... Your suggestion of SFINAE is what I need I think, thanks! I will figure out the exact syntax.

Comment: @Jarod42 you can easily work around it and go `matrix[row][col]` format, if you'll have a proxy class for rows (that doesn't copy data but offers access alias)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's almost a certainty that the reason your template gets selected by overload resolution is because the two parameters you're passing in are not really `size_t`. They're probably `int`s, or something else. If they were truly `size_t`s, then I would expect your non-template overload to be picked. Cleaning that up should make things work, as is, but it's simple enough to make this work in any case.

The usual approach in this kind of a situation is to use SFINAE to exclude the template from participating in overload resolution when the passed-in parameter is `size_t`. Something along the lines of (using C++17):

```
template<class Iterator,
         typename=std::enable_if_t<
                  std::negation_v<std::is_integral_v<Iterator>>>> operator()(Iterator,Iterator)
{
   // ...
}
```

This is your starting point. It's tempting to use `std::is_same_v<Iterator,size_t>`, but you'll quickly discover that this only works if you're passing in exactly a `size_t`. It's very easy for an `int` to slip in there, if you're not careful, and this is going to fall apart in this case. So you'll probably need to use `std::is_integral_v`. Hopefully you're not passing in floating point values anywhere, and rely on them being truncated to the next nearest integer value. If you do, you'll have to tweak this further.

The `std::is_integral_v` and `std::enable_if_t` shortcuts are available only in C++17 (as well as `std::void_t`), but it's simple enough to reinvent that wheel in earlier standards, if necessary.

You can also try using SFINAE in the opposite direction: have this template participate in overload resolution only if `Iterator` resolved to something that `std::iterator_traits` recognizes. The best approach depends on your specific class's requirements.

Comment: That `std::void_t` is unnecessary und really, just use `!` to negate IMO it's clearer or even `std::negation_v`.

Comment: Also if you prefer `std::negation`, I think `_v` has to be removed.

Comment: Thanks a lot that is very clear. Thanks also for leading me around the pitfall, that I would have probably fallen into.